# In q(promise), Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I try to use nodejs's q library, I use Q.fcall and then have the following error.

```
file_path/node_modules/q.js:155
            throw e;
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Promise.apply (/Users/name/Desktop/Programming/video_tutorial_archive/node_modules/q/q.js:1185:25)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/name/Desktop/Programming/video_tutorial_archive/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
at /Users/name/Desktop/Programming/video_tutorial_archive/node_modules/q/q.js:1411:14
at runSingle (/Users/name/Desktop/Programming/video_tutorial_archive/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
at flush (/Users/name/Desktop/Programming/video_tutorial_archive/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

The following is my code:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

Q.fcall(sql_query.select_comment(con,comment))
.then(function(){

    var deferred=Q.defer();
    con.query("SELECT * FROM "+table_video, function (err, result) {
        console.log("step 2 finished");
        console.log("comment is "+comment);
            // if (err) throw err;
            query_result=result;
            // deferred.resolve();

        // console.log(query_result);
    })
    // return deferred.promise;

}).then(function(){
    console.log("step 3 finished");
    console.log("comment is "+comment);
    console.log(query_result);

    res.render('index',{
                result:query_result,
                comment:comment.comment
    });
}).done();

});
```

I can solve it with Q.defer, but I want to use fcall instead. It's cleaner, without all the deferred.promise, and deferred.resolve.

What is causeing the error "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have to pass a function to `Q.fcall()`.  You are passing the return results from `sql_query.select_comment(con,comment)` which his apparently not a function.

To use `Q.fcall()` correct, you pass the first argument as the function you want called and the following arguments are the ones you want passed to that function.  In addition, if you want `select_comment` to still be bound to `sql_query` (I don't know if that is required or not), then you can use `.bind()` to be safe.  You can put that all together like this:

```
Q.fcall(sql_query.select_comment.bind(sql_query), con, comment)
```

The error you get `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` is because the return value from `sql_query.select_comment()` is `undefined` so when `Q.fcall()` tries to use `.apply()` on it to attach the arguments, it throws that error.

You also have another error in that your outer promise is not waiting for `con.query("SELECT * FROM "+table_video, function (err, result) {})` to finish.  The best solution there would be to use only a promise interface to all your DB functions.  Then, you can just return the promise for `con.query()` from inside the `.then()` handler and it will automatically be chained to the parent promise and things will sequence properly.

To see for yourself what's going on inside of `Q.fcall()`, you can look at the source for that function [here on Github](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js#L1522):

```
Q.fcall = function (object /* ...args*/) {
    return Q(object).dispatch("apply", [void 0, array_slice(arguments, 1)]);
};
```

Where this will eventually try to call `.apply()` on the first argument to `Q.fcall()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to separate the params: `Q.fcall(sql_query.select_comment, con, comment)`, just like you would do with `sql_query.select_comment.call(this, con, comment)`

It cannot find `.apply()` because the return value of `sql_query.select_comment(con, comment)` is not a function.